# Most efficient way to move huge amounts of data between MySQL and SQL Server Databases

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I'm looking for an efficient way to move more or less 300GB of data between a MySQL Database and a new SQL Server Database. Any suggestions?

Comment: You may use online copying - create linked MySQL server on Sql Server, query the remote data and insert it into local tables. You may use offline copying - export the data to CSV text files on MySQl then import them on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the [SQL Server Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sql-server-migration-assistant?view=sql-server-ver16) (not to be confused with the Database Migration Assistant - which is a different tool):

> Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) is a tool designed to automate database migration to SQL Server from Microsoft Access, DB2, **MySQL**, Oracle, and SAP ASE.

This will help move not just the data but also the schema which I'm assuming you'd want to not manually manage, given you mentioned this is a new SQL Server instance.